# Remove certain parts of URL with Regex

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I wrote a Git interface in Python which allows me to commit things to my GitHub and Bitbucket repos. In the config file for my local repository, I changed the remote url to

```
https://(Username):(Password)@bitbucket.org/...
```

so that I don't have to enter the password all the time. This works pretty well, but unfortunately, when I push to the repo, Git outputs a message on the console of the form

```
To https://(Username):(Password)@bitbucket.org/...../repo.git
   3f6ac75..16c47c9  master -> master
```

and everybody looking on my screen can view my password. I now want to replace the password with asterisks using regex, so that I get:

```
To https://(Username):*****@bitbucket.org/...../repo.git
   3f6ac75..16c47c9  master -> master
```

I already tried it with `re.sub(r'//.*:.*@.*\..*/', '//(URL hidden)', msg)` but this is ugly. How can I replace the password with asterisks using regex?

Comment: Why aren't you generating the appropriate access tokens for this with the provided APIs?

Comment: Indeed I could store the credentials in the global git config file, but I don't like to do so because I have several different accounts and it sometimes tives troubles when the global config is used. I don't exactly understand what you mean by the provided APIs?

Comment: Are you actually using the bit bucket [API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html) and GitHub [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) ? Also there are Python modules written already to communicate to GitHub as well. Read those, and you can see how you can generate appropriate access keys to use the API instead of using those credentials directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https:\/\/[^:]*:([^@]*)@.*?$
```

Please have a look at the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qO3gA7/2)

Comment: Hmm, `print(re.sub(r'https:\/\/[^:]*:([^@]*)@.*?$', 'abc', "To https://(Username):(Password)@bitbucket.org/...../repo.git"))` just gives me "To abc" and not "To https:// .......". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: this should give you the password that you can replace it with`*****`

Answer (score 1):

You can try following regex:

```
import re

url = u"https://(Username):(Password)@bitbucket.org/...../repo.git"

pattern = re.compile(ur'(http.*:)\(.*?\)(\S*)', re.MULTILINE)
result = re.sub(pattern, "\\1********\\2", url)
```

It will turn

```
https://(Username):(Password)@bitbucket.org/...../repo.git
```

into

```
https://(Username):********@bitbucket.org/...../repo.git
```

See demo [at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xJ9mC6/1)

Answer (score 0):

The last answer brought me the right idea. I now use the following Python code which works very well and reliable:

```
PASS_REGEX = r"(\b(?:[a-z]{,5})://.*:)(.*)(@[^ \b]+)"
PASS_REPLACEMENT = r"\1----------\3"
ret = re.sub(PASS_REGEX, PASS_REPLACEMENT, ret, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

short explanation: start on a word boundary (e.g. start of line or a space etc.) then up to 5 characters follow (git, http, https), then a colon and two slashes, some arbitrary string and again a colon. This is the first group. Then, an arbitrary string follows (this is group 2), followed by an @ and some non-space characters, followed by a word boundary (this is group 3). This pattern is then replaced with the contents of group 1, followed by `----------`,  followed by the contents of group 3. Works well and fixes the URL wherever it occurs.

Info what I need this for: I wrote a Git plugin for Sublime Text. I usually save the username and password for a repository in the .git/config file, because I have different accounts which can lead to trouble when I use
`git config --global`. The problem is, when I push to the repo (no matter whether it is done from Sublime or directly from a terminal), the password is shown by git ("Pushing to https://...username:password@....") and anybody looking on my screen can see it.